# NetBeans - replace in textfiles under a subdirectory

Tags: file, search, netbeans, replace, subdirectory

I have troubles with replacing file contents in my current project. I renamed a directory, and a lot of class names has been changed cause of this. A want to rename this classes with netbeans, but I cannot setup the file path pattern well.

The previous directory path was: Test/TestCase under Source Files, and the new path is Test/UnitTest. So I have to rename the TestCase word to UnitTest in my php files.

I tried with **.php*, it works (of course it works...), but returns every php file in the project which contains that word, and I don't want to choose from circa half thousand files the right ones. The files of the unit test system could easily contain the TestCase word...

Tried out the following patterns, but they gave empty result:

```
Test\UnitTest\*.php
*Test\UnitTest\*.php
Test/UnitTest/*.php
*Test/UnitTest/*.php
Test/UnitTest/*
```

I have not a clue what I do wrong... I tried to search a tutorial for file search patterns but have found only regex patterns and those are definitely not what I was looking for. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Solved with *.php and Test_TestCase_ => Test_UnitTest words, but I'm still curious how to solve this with file name pattern...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol, I checked it again, and I realized, that I didn't notice the "scope" part last time. In that you can choose the current selection instead of the entire project. So the pattern matches only the file name, not the relative path of the file...

It was so obvious... This is an epic fail, I think I was too tired...